# Eclipse LogCat showing system messages but not messages of testing my app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

I know this may have been asked here before, but still didn't get any solution. I have closed logcat and reopened it, closed eclipse then restarted it, nothing helps. This was working perfectly before but suddenly I found out that logcat not showing messages of my apps anymore, it is showing device messages only. I use a spice mobile device instead of emulator, at first I thought it can be a problem related to device, but then tried the same with android emulator and same thing happened. What have gone wrong? What should I do now?

[image]

Comment: create filter for your app package name in logcat

Comment: I tried as I have mentioned that in my question, nothing changed.

Comment: did you tried `adb kill-server
adb start-server` from cmd Go to the <folder_where_your_Android_SDK_is>/platform-tools

Comment: then type both commands one by one

Comment: Yes @KaranMer, I tried so, but the problem still persists

Comment: u use Log.e() or something  like Log.w()?  I need u screenshot of Eclipse and the code u use to log.

Comment: @tinysunlight yes in my code I have used log.e in one line, it was showing before but nothing is showing now, logcat is totally empty

Comment: public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
     super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

     // Make sure that we are currently visible
     if (this.isVisible()) {
         //do nothing
         if (!isVisibleToUser) {
             Log.e("MyFragment", "Not visible anymore.  Stopping audio.");
             // TODO stop audio playback
             
          
             video.pause();
             //video.clearFocus();
             play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
             
         }
     }
 }                 @tinysunlight

Comment: screenshot of the code? or the logcat? @tinysunlight

Comment: the logcat and its frame. compete code of csetUserVisibleHint.assert to error!

Comment: I have solved it. Restored defaults to logcat and then everything is working fine again. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter for your app using the package name.

Eclipse do it automatically when you launch your app, but it fails sometimes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to do this? Any link?

Comment: in logcat window there is small green + button click it and fill filter name and in by application name paste your app package like com.example.yourpackgname

Comment: Are you getting no output when you apply the filter?

Comment: @Nanoc only the device messages I was getting, after adb kill-server adb start-server getting nothing, logcat is empty

Comment: Then it looks that your filter isnt correct for your app, or your app is not running...

Comment: No it was working perfectly, but I don't know what happened suddenly, app is running perfectly'

Comment: As i said eclipse automatically creates a filter when you launch the app for the first time, but sometimes it doesnt...

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]
[image]

Can u see these? Try Android Studio.

images to  all messages!

Comment: I don't use android studio, as I have mentioned

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my logcat as how it looks now. Pardon me for my bad English

Comment: to vorbose!! or restart ur app

Comment: I have already mentioned that I have tried so but nothing helped. Logcat stays empty

Comment: images to  all messages!